# Run Time Error -f1.exe does not exist or is not an executable

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I have a project that makes use of threading in C++ when I clean & build the project it build successfully however when I run the project it pop ups the following errors:

> C:\repos\trunk\logging\build\Debug\MinGW_1-Windows\tests\TestFiles\f1.exe doesnot exist or is not an executable.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked that the file `f1.exe` actually exists? It might be that there is an error but it's hidden among the other build messages?

Comment: You meant i need to check in this path ,well there is no folder named TestFiles so there is no f1.exe acutually when i was running it earlier without the use of threading it was running successfully however it does not run now.

Comment: Then you need to go through the changes you made from when it was working until it's not, and see what might have caused the problem. There is not enough information in your question to say more at the moment.

Comment: Ok i will undo the changes and see if it works.

Comment: The problem is still there , i dont know what happened but undoing the changes didnt help.

Comment: Run depends.exe on the `f1.exe` file, perhaps you are missing a DLL it needs to run?  Try running it in the debugger to see if some other error fires.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] Error: "Does not exist or is not executable"

Menu Bar -> Run -> Set Project Configuration -> "Release".

It was "Debug" previously, this worked out for me. Hope work for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

"when I run the project"

What does this mean?  Are you running the project by clicking a button in your IDE?  If so, you need to find out what the IDE thinks is your project executable.  ( How to do that depends on your IDE which you do not mention. )

It lloks like you have build a debug version of your project.  Have you tried running it under the debugger?